# Multiple Bootstrap Vertical Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the vertical menu from the link below:

```
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/BapPE
```

My problem is when I have two on the same page they are conflicting with each other. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction for having two vertical menus on one single page that do not conflict with each other. Below is my fiddle so you can see what I am talking about.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/1g8xfqe4/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `toggle` the `.ppit-tab-content` you just need to add its parent `.ppit-tab-container` to make it work fine.

I made some changes to your script and it work fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/1g8xfqe4/1/

```
$("div.ppit-tab-menu>div.list-group>a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var thisParent = $(this).closest('.ppit-tab-container');
  $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var index = $(this).index();
  $("div.ppit-tab>div.ppit-tab-content", thisParent).removeClass("active");
  $("div.ppit-tab>div.ppit-tab-content", thisParent).eq(index).addClass("active");
});
```